# Website header does not stretch 100% on window resize

Tags: html, css, window-resize

So my website http://dealminion.com has a header that is set to 100%. However if I resize the browser window then scroll to the right the header stops but the page keeps going. It's very odd. If you go to the site and resize the window you will see what I am saying.
Here is the css:

```
#header-intro { 
width: 100%; 
position: absolute; 
height: 600px; 
padding-top: 25px;
background-color: #657b90;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 2px -2px #777777;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 2px -2px #777777;
box-shadow: 0 5px 2px -2px #777777;
behavior: url('pie.htc');
}
```

and the body css:

```
html, body { 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Is there any reason why this is happening?

Comment: What browser does this happen in? Quick look in chrome showed no problem.

Comment: because your `div#info` have `padding:10px`. so total has `100%+20px`

Comment: having same problem .. even google have the same problem check google.com .. i guess it have no answer . i wonder how u managed to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

It's stretching to contain your `#info` element which has `width: 100%` and `padding: 10px`, effectively causing 20px of overflowed content.

Since `#info` is a block-level element, you don't need to set the width to 100%. Just set `width: auto` (or don't set it at all), and it will fill the available space, making allowances for padding, borders, and margins, without causing overflow.

```
#info {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #314455;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto; /* changed to auto */
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish.

Since it's absolutely positioned, the width collapses. Instead of setting your width explicitly for that element, set it implicitly with `left` and `right`.

```
#info {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #314455;
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but the `#info` now just stretches to fit the test "How it works". It's no longer stretching at all.

Comment: The suggestions are all great, I never know you could do it that way Brent, you too Giberno. However, the header still stop at the right edge of the browser window when I make it smaller. Then scrolling to the right it stops filling the page and it looks cut off.

Answer (score 0):

if you do not any element in your `#info`, try:

```
#info {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #314455;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
#info a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: @Naterade, because you set ` #wrapper{width: 1020px;}` so if you want `stop at the right edge`, add `min-width:1020px` in your `body,html`